# Processing Multiple urls using go routines

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to validates a list of urls using http.Get() method of Golang. The issue I am facing is there are certain urls in the list who are taking lot of time before giving timeout error.I need to handle those urls so, I can give a timeout error after a certain period of time.
so far I have tried this much

```
const timeout time.Duration = 5 * time.Second
type urlRow struct {
    id     int32
    url    string
    teamId int32
}
var myCertCheckResults = []certCheckResult{}

type httpResponse struct {
    url      string
    response *http.Response
    err      error
}
func asyncHTTPGets(url string, ch chan *httpResponse) {
    go func(url string) {
        resp, err := http.Get("****/url?url=" + url)
        ch <- &httpResponse{url, resp, err}
    }(url)
}
func main() {
    var myUrlRows = []urlRow{}
    log.Println("INFO - BatchURLValidateListFromDB: Begin - Checking certs for URLs in the database table")

    dbconn, err := getPgDbConn()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERR - BatchURLValidateListFromDB: Error getting db connection:", err)
        
    }
    //defer dbconn.Close()

    rows, err := runPgQuery(dbconn, "select id, url, team_id from cert_url where active_flag = true;")
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERR - BatchURLValidateListFromDB: Error querying list of URLs to validate:", err)
        
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var myUrlRow urlRow
        err := rows.Scan(&myUrlRow.id, &myUrlRow.url, &myUrlRow.teamId)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("ERR - BatchURLValidateListFromDB: Failed to scan rows: ", err)
        } else {
            myUrlRows = append(myUrlRows, myUrlRow)
        }
    }
    responseCount := 0
    ch := make(chan *httpResponse)
    for _, url := range myUrlRows {
        go asyncHTTPGets(url.url, ch)
    }
    for responseCount != len(myUrlRows) {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            if r.err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error %s fetching %s\n", r.err, r.url)
            } else {

                fmt.Println(r.url, " was fetched\n", responseCount)
            }
            responseCount++
        case <-time.After(timeout):
           
            fmt.Println("connection timeout")
            responseCount++
        }
    }
}
```

**In second case of select statement if I can access the channel data then the problem is solved but how to access it?
To answer the question why do I need there, I need it because the data from channel will be appended to a slice called myCertCheckResult**

Comment: the http.Client has a timout built in https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client

Comment: Alternatively you could use a context, but timeout seems more appropriate

Comment: If the timeouts needed are not consistent across requests, it's probably more convenient to use a context in the requests rather than multiple clients.